# SqlDataAdapter filling with DataTable does not work

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sqldataadapter

I have this code running in form_load event:

```
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", sqlConn);
            DataTable sqlDt = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", 7));
            sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
            dgvMachineAndOp.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dgvMachineAndOp.DataSource = sqlDt;

            sqlDa.Dispose();
            sqlConn.Close();

        }
```

I get error *'Procedure or function 'pp_sp_MachineAndOp' expects parameter '@MachineAndOpID', which was not supplied.'* at line:

```
                sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
```

Important to say that if I open DataTable Visualizer of sqlDt at runtime I see expected results!

[image]

Here is a code behind Helper.ExecuteDataTable:

```
        public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName, params SqlParameter[] arrParam)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // Open the connection 
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            try
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                // Define the command 
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

                    // Handle the parameters 
                    if (arrParam != null)
                    {
                        foreach (SqlParameter param in arrParam)
                        {
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                        }
                    }

                    // Define the data adapter and fill the dataset 
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }
        return dt;
    }
```

What I am missing?

Comment: `Helper.ExecuteDataTable` is custom code, we can't tell you what's wrong with it from a distance. I will say it's highly suspicious that you need to mention `pp_sp_MachineAndOp` twice, once in the constructor for the `SqlDataAdapter` and then another time in the helper. In a proper design there would be no need to repeat it. I suspect that `Helper.ExecuteDataTable` is designed to do all the work and there is no need to involve an `SqlDataAdapter` at all.

Comment: I have added code behind Helper.ExecuteDataTable.

Comment: As you can see, `Helper.ExecuteDataTable` indeed does all the work to give you `sqlDt`, complete with its own `SqlDataAdapter`. Why are you using your own? All you need is `DataTable sqlDt = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", 7));` and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything except

```
 DataTable sqlDt = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", 7));
dgvMachineAndOp.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgvMachineAndOp.DataSource = sqlDt;
```

your Helper.ExecuteDataTable is doing everything. you don't need to replicate same this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your helper class is creating connection with database as your data table has data.

So, try to remove stored proc name and connection object from adaptor and then check.

SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();//use this only.

Comment: I tried this it now I get error: 'The SelectCommand property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'.' I will add Helper.ExecuteDataTable code in few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function(modification required as per your need):

```
 public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string spName, object[] parameterValues)
    {
        command = GetCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = spName;
        if (parameterValues != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterValues.Length; i++)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameterValues[i]);
            }
        }
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (parameterValues != null)
            command.Parameters.Clear();
        return reader;
    }
```